# Help required with a complex self join sql query

Tags: sql, key, composite

myTable is having composite key formed of columns A and B (total columns A, B, C, D, E).

I want to exclude/ignore records where value of D (say order number) is same and E (say decision) is Y in one but N or Null in other. (means all the twin-records with same order number (equal D value) which were ordered first (so E=Y) and then again cancelled (so E=N) should be ignored)

So I pulled out A,B for all records where D is same but E is Y in one and N in other

```
SELECT * 
FROM myTable A, myTable B 
WHERE 
(A.D=B.D)
AND
((A.E ='Y' AND (B.E ='N' OR B.E IS NULL)) OR (B.E='Y' AND (A.E='N' OR A.E IS NULL)))
```

Now my final output should be all records from myTable but not the records found above.

I wrote a join query but its not working as it should. Basically issue is how to compare two composite keys ??

Sample Data:

```
A    B     C     D     E
=========================    
1    A     xyz   ONE   Y
2    B     pqr   TWO   Y
3    C     lmn   ONE   N
4    D     abc   THREE Y
5    E     ijk   FOUR  Y
=========================
```

Thus, my output should be records 2,4 and 5. As 1 and 3 will be ignored. Because 1.D = 3.D and 1.E is Y but 3.E is N.

Thanks,
Nik

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do and why not to write
SELECT * from myTable WHERE CANCEL_FLAG != 'XYZ'
if I understood correctly what you want?

Comment: Can you give some example data, and then give your desired result for that example data? It would make your question 30 times easier to understand.

Comment: @Mark: updated the question with sample data

Comment: This is very similar to (if not an exact duplicate of) [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6951511/sql-query-with-self-join).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've correctly understood you, what you need is this:

```
select x.*
from mytable x left outer join
    (   select mt1.a, mt1.b
        from mytable mt1 inner join
            mytable mt2 on mt1.d = mt2.d
        where ((mt1.E ='Y' AND (mt2.E ='N' OR mt2.E IS NULL)) OR (mt2.E='Y' AND (mt1.E='N' OR mt1.E IS NULL)))
    ) y on x.a = y.a and x.b = y.b
where y.a is NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want to exclude records where value of D is "XYZ".

Why not simply query like this directly?

```
select  *
from    myTable
where   D <> 'XYZ'
```

To exclude rows from `Temp`, you could:

```
select  *
from    myTable 
where   not exists
        (
        select  *
        from    temp
        where   myTable.A = temp.A
                and myTable.B = temp.B
        )
```

Or with an exclusive left join:

```
select  *
from    myTable 
left join
        temp
on      myTable.A = temp.A
        and myTable.B = temp.B
where   temp.A is null
```

Answer (score 0):

You need something like

```
select A.*
from myTable A 
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myTable B WHERE B.D = A.D AND (B.E IS NULL OR B.E = 'N')) = 0
```